# When do we call onCreateView method in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have just started learning android using Big Nerds Ranch Guide. We are implementing a list adapter to display the list.
I don't quite get why we did not call the list adapter in `onCreateView()`. As far as I know, we call `onCreateView` to display the contents of the fragment. Using `listAdapter` actually displays the list on the device's screen. So why not implement that in `onCreateView` method?

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflator inflator, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v=inflator.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,parent,false)// I used this layout because that is what presenting the list. 
    listOfCrime = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrimes();
    ArrayAdapter<Crime> listAdaptor = new ArrayAdapter<Crime>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listOfCrime);
    setListAdapter(listAdaptor);
}
```

As expected, this approach fails. Why do we need to implement that list adaptor in `onCreate` method of our fragment? Why does my approach fail? Please explain in detail.

Comment: missing return v; at the end of the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first define ListView widget in your layout (`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` is not layout which contains ListView, it's is layout item for ListView) and setAdater to ListView widget.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflator inflator, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View v=inflator.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,parent,false); // This is not layout with list, you must create new, add ListView and insert layout here instead of android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, because it's only item
    listOfCrime=CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrimes();
    ArrayAdapter<Crime> listAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<Crime>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listOfCrime);
    ListView listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    return v;
}
```